# Смысл слова "абазурник"?

Tags: диалектология

Ответьте, пожалуйста, что обозначает слово "абазурник" (записано так, как услышала звучание этого слова) в псковских говорах? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

[Русский этимологический словарь. Вып. 1 (а – аяюшка) Александр Аникин](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=-Z3SAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=Z1vzrxHomq&sig=Ev8r6Sh9y3_LIQBwWSOWDl-r7OE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Uq1RVcqiHoqeywPrtIHoCg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false) дает такое определение слову **абазурник**: "тот кто упрямый, неслух".

Вот статья целиком:

> [image: Статья абазурить]
>   [image: продолжение статьи]

Comment: Смотрите-ка, а Змiцер в этимологии был не так далеко от истины. Если бы не постоянное выпячивание своей "беларуской" неграмотности, получил бы плюс. )))

Answer (score 1):

Есть город Абаза. Возможно, данное слово является устаревшим названием его жителей.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, абазурник - это абажурник в псковском говоре.

В результате древних контактов с балтийскими и финно-угорскими языками (в эстонском языке, например, известны только свистящие звуки и неизвестны шипящие), поэтому у древних псковичей **преобладание свистящего звука.** Отсюда и своеобразное псковское произношение Шосна «сосна«; уЗжнали «узнали« и Суба «шуба«, Заних «жених« преимущественно в районах Нижневеликорецкой зоны (Печерском, Псковском, Палкинском) и в Гдовском районе (Северная зона).

http://gubernia.pskovregion.org/number_26/7.php

ЕЩЕ ОДНА ВЕРСИЯ/ГИПОТЕЗА

Существует диалектный глагол "базулить" (также базурить, базурничать).

(1) Базулить - баловать кого-то,  тешиться, забавляться чем, дав себе волю. Согласно этому, можно предположить, что такое прозвище получал шаловливый, неугомонный ребенок, разбалованный своими родителями.

(2) Глагол распространен в ярославских и донских диалектах русского языка, где он имеет значение «тешиться, забавляться чем-то, дав себе волю». Таким образом, базукой именовали шалуна, баловника, повесу, который имел репутацию веселого и жизнелюбивого человека.

Таким образом: базурить - обазуриться - обазурник.

Answer (score 0):

Есть слово "абаза", но не знаю его значения.

Answer (score 0):

Может, **аркебузник**? Или **абажурник**?

Насчет "Абазы" - не думаю. Фонетика не предполагает. Откуда там "урник"?